# No comprendo esta función para ordenar palabras con números de una frase

Tags: javascript

Es una función en el que el parámetro es una frase. Cada palabra de la frase tiene un número y esta función retorna un string con esas palabras ordenadas dependiendo del número que tienen. Soy nuevo en esto y no entendí.

```
 function order(words){
  return words.split(' ').sort(function(a, b){
      return a.match(/\d/) - b.match(/\d/);
   }).join(' ');
}
```

Se lo que hace todo pero aún así no entendí la parte en la que pone parámetros a b (no sé cuáles son esos) y luego los resta tampoco lo entiendo.

Comment: Ya investigaste lo que hace [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)? Ya investigaste lo que hace [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)? ya investigaste lo que hace [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)? Ya investigaste lo que hace [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Comment: Se lo que hace todo pero aún así no entendí la parte en la que pone parámetros a b (no sé cuáles son esos) y luego los resta tampoco lo entiendo

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta no deberia haberse marcado con votos negativos, en este caso esta pidiendo una explicacion y nos esta dando codigo, yo la considero una buena pregunta, simple pero con fundamento, si bien todo eso lo puede investigar el `OP`, nos esta mostrando un codigo especifico, y ya nos ha dicho que ha investigado, pero que aun asi no entiende, la verdad entiendo lo de las preguntas basadas en opiniones, es decir, se que las basadas en opiniones no deberian responderse, y en eso tienen razon, pero en esta pregunta no me parece correcto catalogarla como poco util.

Comment: Es decir, ya la comunidad se esta tornando sobre algo demasiado especifico, se que stackoverflow no es un foro como yahoo respuestas, pero tampoco consideraria malo hecharle una mano a alguien que de por si nos esta proveyendo de al menos un codigo, algo minimo, se trata de un nuevo usuario, y no creo que deberiamos ser tan duros con usuarios nuevos, en fin yo voto arriba por tu pregunta y si alguien no te da una respuesta yo te la dare, no me gusta en este caso las acciones de la comunidad. Y voto arriba de mi parte

Comment: Por ultimo me refiero a que... tanto cuesta explicarle al OP algo que no entiende?, yo puedo llegar a investigar mucho, pero si no entiendo algo y acudo a esta comunidad y la comunidad prefiere decirme que mejor siga buscando, entonces a quien acudo?, a ver.... para que existe esta comunidad entonces?

Comment: @Jesús podrias poner porfavor la llamada a la funcion con los parametros que le pasas, es decir, un ejemplo, con datos de prueba, ya que segun tu descripcion no basta con que el parametro sea un string, si no que tambien es dado otra condiciones.

Comment: @Riven A mi modo de ver, lo peor de la pregunta era el título, que no ayudaba a nadie más porque no especificaba nada concreto. (ponia **¿Por qué esto funciona?** lo cual ya me diras si alguien entrará a ver lo que dice o no). La idea del sitio es colaborar y ayudarnos entre todos, y con ese título poco iba a ayudar a nadie más. Por otra parte, expresar solo un "no lo entiendo" sin decir que ha investigado, en que punto se ha encallado exactamente, es solicitar un tipo de ayuda quizás demasiado opinable según lo que interprete cada uno que responda.

Comment: @Riven En los comentarios ha expresado lo que tenia que tenia que haber puesto en la pregunta tambien para que fuera mejor aceptada. **Se lo que hace todo pero aún así no entendí la parte en la que pone parámetros a b (no sé cuáles son esos) y luego los resta tampoco lo entiendo**.  O sea, lo que no entiende es la resta para efectuar una ordenación, y así si que podemos acotar bastante más la explicación y no seria tan "opinable".

Answer (score 6):

Veamos, tenemos una función que en general recibe un `string` que es una frase con números y devuelve otro `string` con las palabras de la entrada ordenadas por los números que contiene. Es decir, recibe algo como:

> "hola2 perro1 sapo3 entender5 tamarindo4"

Y debería devolver:

> "perro1 hola2 sapo3 tamarindo4 entender5"

¿Qué es lo primero que debemos hacer?

Pues antes de comenzar a ordenar, debemos separar el string `words` que nos llega en palabras. Es decir, esa gran cadena de entrada hay que picarla en pedacitos que ordenaremos después. Eso es precisamente lo que viene a hacer `words.split(' ')`. Esta sentencia `splits`(corta) la cadena por pedazos devolviendo un `array`. ¿Y cómo sabe dónde cortar? Pues sabe cómo cortar por el parámetro que se le pasa. En este caso `words.split(' ')` dice lo siguiente "corta la cadena `words` en cuanto veas un espacio en blanco".

¿Lo probamos?

```js
let words = "hola2 perro1 sapo3 entender5 tamarindo4"
console.log(words.split(' '))
```

Perfecto, ya tenemos la lista de palabras separadas en un `array`. ¿Cómo las ordenamos ahora? Pues resulta que los `arrays` tienen una función que se llama `sort` y hace el trabajo de ordenación por nosotros, pero tiene su truquillo.

`sort()` recibe como parámetro una función que va a definir el orden en que queremos ordenar. Esta función tiene unas características especiales:

- Debe tomar como argumento dos de las cosas que queremos ordenar.
- Debe retornar `0` si esas dos cosas son iguales.
- Debe retornar `un número mayor que cero` si la primera cosa es más grande que la segunda.
- Debe retornar `un número menor que cero` si la primera cosa es menor que la segunda.

Ok, un poco complicado esto último pero arrojemos luz. Vamos a centrarnos en comparar las `cosas`. Vamos a esbozar esa función. La función debe recibir dos parámetros:

```
function(word1, word2) { } // Toma dos palabras de la lista
```

Ahora bien,
¿cómo sabemos si una palabra es mayor que otra? ¡Claro! ¡Por su número! pero ¿Cómo sacamos el número?

Pues acá entra el `word1.match(/\d/)`. Esta sentencia toma el valor de la palabra `word1` y devuelve los dígitos `\d` que haya en esa palabra. Por tanto si le entra `hola2` devuelve `2` si le entra `perro1` devuelve `1`, etc.

Ahora bien, ya podemos sacar el número de cada palabra, ¿pero como comparamos según los criterios? Analicemos las propiedades de la resta de `a - b`:

- Si `a = b` entonces retorna `0`
- Si `a > b` retorna un número mayor que cero.
- Si `a < b` retorna un número menor que cero.

¿Te suena esto de algo? Pues la resta tiene las mismas características de la función que recibe `sort`, por lo que podemos escribir la función cómo:

```
function(word1, word2) {
   return word1.match(/\d/) - word2.match(/\d/); 
}
```

Nota que extrae los números de las dos palabras que se le pasan como argumentos y devuelve la resta de los números, que cumple con las condiciones de ordenamiento, por tanto ya podemos escribir y probar:

```js
let words = "hola2 perro1 sapo3 entender5 tamarindo4"

function order(words){
  return words.split(' ').sort(function(word1, word2){
      return word1.match(/\d/) - word2.match(/\d/);
   })
}

console.log(order(words))
```

Falta un último detalle. Como ves, hasta ahorita devuelve un `arreglo`. Hemos separado la frase en palabras cortándola por espacios y convirtiéndola en `arreglo`, luego la ordenamos y ya tenemos la lista ordenada, pero, ¿Cómo la volvemos a unir? Es ahí donde entra `join(' ')`

`array.join(' ')` une todos los elementos de un `array` en un `string` poniendo un espacio en blanco `' '` por medio de cada elemento. Sabiendo esto, implementemos:

```js
let words = "hola2 perro1 sapo3 entender5 tamarindo4"

function order(words){
  return words.split(' ').sort(function(word1, word2){
      return word1.match(/\d/) - word2.match(/\d/);
   }).join(' ')
}

console.log(order(words))
```

Nota que ahora la función devuelve una cadena en lugar de un array, con todas las palabras ordenadas.

En resumen:

- Se separa la cadena original por espacios convirtiéndola en un arreglo.
- Se ordena el arreglo con `sort` pasando como parámetro la función que define el orden.
- Se une el arreglo ordenado y se retorna.

Espero te haya quedado claro. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por dar una respuesta tan bien planteada. Entiendo que el sitio tiene normas y que quizás la pregunta pueda no cumplir alguna de ellas. Pero creo que es fundamental que así como nosotros en ocasiones nos apoyamos en otros usuarios para resolver nuestras inquietudes, podamos dar una mano a alguien que quizás está comenzando y para quien puede ser duro procesar tanta información junta aun investigando o leyendo documentaciones, creo que todos en algún momento estuvimos en esa misma situación. Un placer leerte y quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo entendí. Lo siento por lo de que formulé mal la pregunta, lo haré bien si hago más. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por dar una respuesta jaime y por brindarle apoyo al `OP`, que bueno que hayas apoyado al usuario dandole tan buena respuesta.

Comment: Voto por más respuestas como esta, muy bien elaborada y explicada paso a paso. @Jesús, si te sirvió, por favor márcala como aceptada.